# Mac OS X: Make home directory at login via SSH

Tags: macos, ssh, ldap, pam, home-directory

I have **LDAP** server on Ubuntu 12.04 and **Mac OS X 10.7.5 client** configured via Directory Service. The NFSHomeDirectory property mapped to #/Users/$uid$. LDAP users can login to Mac via login screen or via SSH. When user login from login screen the system creates proper home directory (if it wasn't made before) and everything works fine.

**Problem: When user login via SSH the home directory is not creating.**

I've tried to enable **pam_mkhomedir.so** module at **/etc/pam.d/sshd**. But when I do it ssh stop working. The skeleton directory I tried: **/System/Library/User\ Template/English.lproj**. There are rumors that mkhomedir pam modile is not built in into OS X, but custom build of pam is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to solve the similar problem.
createhomedir utility can do the job, but I can not locate pam_exec.so on Mac OS to call the thing.
The dirty hack is to write /etc/sshrc (which is similar to /etc/profile, but called at ssh session start time) calling small wrapper with suid bit on, which in turn calls "`createhomedir -c -u username`". Skip the steps if home directory exists or if terminal is absent.